# how to use ffmpeg to set inband-fec when encoding opus with libopus

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, encoder, opus

I'm learning ffmpeg to encode opus using libopus, I can set inband-fec in libopus like `opus_encoder_ctl(aEncoder_, OPUS_SET_INBAND_FEC(1))`, but when I use ffmpeg I cannot do that, I tried `opt = av_opt_find(m_codec_ctx, "inband_fec", NULL, 0, 0);` and `ret = av_opt_set_int(m_codec_ctx, "inband_fec",1, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);` but got `option not found`,
so is there any way to set inband-fec in ffmepg when using libopus?

Comment: Not implemented. Give me a few days. Remind me by Monday if I don't get back.

Comment: @Gyan Your FFmpeg efforts are always very appreciated.  :-)

Comment: Patch in review. Will  update when applied.

Comment: @Gyan so, where can I see this patch?

Comment: See https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20200906065728.6153-1-ffmpeg@gyani.pro/

Comment: Applied to git master.